# Mcrypt_encrypt will not work

Tags: php, mcrypt

I was told that encryption is the best way to send vars. So i've found a piece of code but i wont work

```
$salt = 'test';
function simple_encrypt($text){ // line 9
    return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
} // line 11

function simple_decrypt($text){
    return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, base64_decode($text), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)));
}
```

the error is:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare simple_encrypt() (previously declared in /home/baspeters/domains/bas-peters.nl/public_html/Forum2/inc/settings.php:9) in /home/baspeters/domains/bas-peters.nl/public_html/Forum2/inc/settings.php on line 11
```

Comment: You're probably including or requiring the file more than once.

Comment: no i've only included it in the top of the index.php

    `<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(~0);
    ob_start();
    include("inc/config.php");
    
    include("inc/dateTimeToNL.func.php");
    
    include("inc/settings.php");
    
    include("content/check.php");
    
    include("content/adminFunctions.php");
    ?>`

it's the settings.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the simple_encrypt function declared twice. Make sure you're not including a file that also has simple_encrypt defined in it.